# Title for the next page appearing under the same background image

Tags: html, css, image, frontend

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>James McGill</title>
        <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md sticky-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">J.M</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About me</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact me</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <section class="intro">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="content">
            <h1>Hello there!</h1>
            <h3>My name is James McGill and I'm a front-end web developer.</h3>
          </div>
    </section>

      <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>My skills</h1>
        <br><br>
        <h2>HTML</h2>
        <div>90%</div>
        <h2>CSS</h2>
        <div>70%</div>
        <h2>Javascript</h2>
        <div>60%</div>
        <h2>jQuery</h2>
        <div>55%</div>
      </div>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
        background-image: url("https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/2000/1*M6iNwOtplNTw1EOTcUklkQ.png");
        background-size: cover; /*This makes the image cover the whole page space*/
        background-position: center;

         color: white !important;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
}

.intro {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

nav .navbar-nav li a {
  color: white !important;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  }

 .navbar-brand {
  color: white !important;
  }

  .content {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25%; 
    text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Hey guys,
if you view my site on your browser you will see that as you scroll down the 'h1' which says "My skills" is located just before the start of the next page.

https://codepen.io/JamesMcGill/pen/KGNEWd On codepen it's even worse.

I am having a difficult time trying to figure out why this is happening.

Well, technically it is not on the same page. However, it does appear within the same background image as the contents on the main welcoming page.

Please, give me some suggestions on how I might be able to address this issue.

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You applied the background-image to the body element, which will cause it to fill the screen. If you want it to only cover the first section, you should apply the background-image rule to that specific section.

It is doubling up at the bottom because `background-repeat: repeat` is the default and you have not declared an alternative. If you want if to fill the screen, you can add `background-size: cover`, or simply add `background-repeat: no-repeat` to prevent the doubling.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel. This helped a lot.